# How do I search Info for help on a given keyword or function?

Tags: help-mode, info

Occasionally looking up a function with `C-h f` will cross reference to an Info node in the manual, but that is pretty rare. I often want a way to jump from the help documentation on a given function to the corresponding documentation referencing it in Info, but I have yet to find an easy way to do that. `info-finder` can sort of work on categories, and of course it's possible to manually search through various Info manuals from the root menu at `C-h i`.

I have found `info-apropos`, which can be a little slow. It appears to read and index every Info file for every keyword search. Is there a better or faster method for looking up a keyword in Info? Is there a way to pre-index `info-apropos`? Is there a nice way to jump from the help for a function to related Info pages?

Comment: Do you mean like elisp keywords or per programming language keyword? (The latter would be...amazing, methinks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to `info-lookup-symbol` (`C-h S`), if you use library [help-fns+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help-fns%2b.el) then `C-h f`, `C-h v`, or `C-h k` includes a link to look up the function (or variable etc.) in the manuals (using the index).

You control which manuals are searched by way of user option `help-cross-reference-manuals`. The default behavior is to look in the Emacs and Elisp manuals.

See [Links to Manuals](http://www.emacswiki.org/HelpPlus#LinksToManuals).

Answer (score 5):

`info-lookup-symbol` bound by default to `C-h S` can search info indices to find the relevant node for symbol corresponding to point.

Comment: Find it very limiting.

Answer (score 4):

I have since found that `elisp-index-search` and `emacs-index-search` are also quite useful. They search for indexed topics in the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual or the Emacs User Manual respectively.